# Problems to compress Excel files, JAVA

Tags: java, compression, huffman-code

I have some problems compressing excel files using the Hffman algorthim. The thing is that my code seems to work with .txt files, but when I'm trying to compress .xlsx or older versions of excel an error occurs.

First of all, I read my file like this:

```
File file = new File("fileName.xlsx");
        byte[] dataOfFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        dis.readFully(dataOfFile);
        dis.close();
```

To check this (if everything seems OK) I use this code:

```
String entireFileText = new String(dataOfFile, "UTF-8");

    for(int i=0;i<dataOfFile.length;i++)
  {
  System.out.print(dataOfFile[i]);
  }
```

By doing this to a .txt file I get something like this (which seems to be OK):

"7210110810811132119111114108100331310721111193297114101321211111173"

But when I use this on .xlsx file I get this and I think the hyphen makes errors that might occur later in the compression:

"8075342006080003301165490-90122100-1245001908291671111101161011101169584121112101115934612010910832-944240-96020000000000000"... and so on

Anyway, by using a string a can map this into a HashMap, where I count the frequency of each character. I have a HashMap:

public static HashMap map;

```
public static boolean countHowOftenACharacterAppear(String s1) {
  String s = s1;
  for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
     char c = s.charAt(i);
     Integer val = map.get(new Character(c));
     if(val != null){
       map.put(c, new Integer(val + 1));
     }
     else{
       map.put(c,1);
     }
  }
 return true;
```

}

When I compress my string I use:

```
 public static String compress(String s) {
 String c = new String();

 for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
     c = c + fromCharacterToCode.get(s.charAt(i));

 return c;
```

}

fromCharactertoCode is another HashMap of type :
public static HashMap fromCharacterToCode;

(I'm traversing through my table I've built. Dont't think this is the problem)

Anyway, the results from this using the .txt file is:

"01000110110111011011110001101110011011000001000000000"... (PERFECT)

From the .xlsx file:

"10101110110001110null0010000null0011000nullnullnull10110000null00001101011111" ...

I really don't get why I'm getting the nullpointers on the .xlsx files. I would be very happy if I could get some help here to solve this. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is java I/O, well before getting to compression.

First, you don't really need DataInputStream here, but leave that aside. You then convert to String entireFileText assuming the contents of the file is text in UTF-8, whereas data files like .xlsx aren't text at all and many text files even on Windows aren't UTF-8. But you don't seem to use entireFileText, so that may not matter. If you do, and the file isn't plain ASCII text, your compressor will "lose" chunks of it and the output of decompression will be only a fraction of the compression input; that is usually considered unsatisfactory.

Then you extract each byte from dataOfFile. byte in Java is signed; plain ASCII text files will have only "positive" bytes 0x00 to 0x7F (and usually all 0x20 to 0x7E plus 0x09 0x0D 0x0A), but everything else (UTF-8 text, UTF-16 text, data, and executables) will have "negative" bytes 0x80 to 0xFF which come out as -0x80 to -0x01.

Your printout "7210110810811132119111114108100331310721111193297114101321211111173" for "the .txt file" is almost certainly the byte sequence 72=H 101=e 108=l 108=l 111=o 32=space 119=w 111=o 114=r 108=l 100=d 33=! 13=CR 10=LF 72=H 111=o 119=w 32=space 97=a 114=r 101=e 32=space 121=y 111=o 117=u 3=(ETX aka ctrl-C) (how did you get a ctrl-C into a file?! or was it really 30=ctrl-Z? that's somewhat usual for Windows text files)

Someone more familiar with .xlsx format might be able to reconstruct that one, but I can tell you right off the hyphens are due to bytes with negative values, printed in decimal (by default) as -128 to -1.

For a general purpose compressor, you shouldn't ever convert to java char's and String's; those are designed for text and not all files are text. Just work with bytes, but if you want them in consistently positive, mask with & 0xFF .